# How to resize/change the layout of a foreground image

Tags: vb.net, image, layout, resize, gif

I need an image to display and run a .gif, and therefore it must run in the foreground, but the image I am using from a resources folder is not the same size it will need to be when actually in the program. I can change the *BackgroundImageLayout* property, but that doesn't do anything to the image as it is *Image* and not *BackgroundImage*

Put simply, is there any way I can resize a foreground image without having to create a new copy of the image that's the right size?

Comment: You can't resize the image itself without creating a new one, no. But if you're using a `PictureBox` you can change [how the image is resized/repositioned with the control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.picturebox.sizemode(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Thanks, never realised VB had a property "SizeMode", wish it was more consistent with its naming etc